# Personalized URL for each user using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to create a site where each user has his own home page and where the URL is in the format `site\username`. How can I accomplish this with ASP.NET MVC routing system?

I'm planning the follow URL layout:

> mysite/ -> home page
>   mysite/account/register -> account register page
>   mysite/user1 -> user1 home page
>   mysite/user2 -> user2 home page

The above URL would match the following `controller\action` pattern:

> mysite/ -> home/index
>   mysite/account/register -> account/register
>   mysite/user1 -> user/index
>   mysite/user2 -> user/index

How can I arrange my RegisterRoutes to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "User",
    "{username}",
    new { controller ="User", action="Index" }
);
```

Edit: Those worrying about users maliciously (or accidentally) breaking this format by making their username as "account" or something similar should look to [this link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/01/11/asp-net-mvc-route-constraints.aspx).

Comment: i smell danger. what if a user chooses the username 'account'?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a route like `mysite/user1` you would probably need to use a route like `mysite/users/user1`.  Then map it to the `user/index` action and have it pass the last part (user name) as a parameter to that method.

The problem with using `mysite/{username}` is what if someone decides to use `account` or something similar as their username?  It would likely make their page unviewable.

Comment: Very valid concern, but the list of protected usernames probably wouldn't exceed ~100 or so, could make an enum to help validate it.